# How to geometrically prove this property of hyperbola and ellipse?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

> Let $H$ be a hyperbola with center $F_0$, foci $F_1$, $F_2$ and directrices $L_{D_1}$ and $L_{D_2}$ corresponding to the foci $F_1$ and $F_2$ respectively, $L_T$ is a line tangent to $H$ at $T$ ($T$ closer to $F_2$), $L_1=\{F_0+t\overrightarrow{{F_0}T}\}$, ${L_1}\cap{L_{D_2}}=Q$ and $L_2=\{F_2+\lambda\overrightarrow{{F_2}Q}\}$. Prove that $L_2{\bot}L_T$.

This can be proved if we assume the equation of the hyperbola is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, so the equation of the tangent line at a point $T=(x_0,y_0)$ of the hyperbola is $\frac{{x_0}x}{a^2}-\frac{{y_0}y}{b^2}=1$ and we can get an analytic solution to the problem, but I'm trying to get an euclidean solution.

I tried using the reflective property of the hyperbola, the property of the right angle at the focus and $TF_1-TF_2={F_1}{F_2}$ to demonstrate that some triangles are similar, but got nowhere.

This property is also true for the ellipse if you replace the word "hyperbola" with "ellipse" in the original statement.

Any suggestion to get an euclidean solution to the problem presented, be it for the case of the hyperbola or the ellipse, will be very helpful.

Comment: Not a solution, but here's a Geogebra diagram of the property of the hyperbola in which you can move the point $T$ (and thereby change the directrices): https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/f6b6ezbg